# Re-render component everytime screen is opened react native

Tags: react-native

I'm kinda new to React Native. I'm using the `getFamily()` on my screen MyFamily but when I go to another screen there change the value of the Family and come back to my MyFamily screen then I don't see the changes.
I tried doing it with the `useEffect` but still nothing happens, also the log doesn't happen. How can I solve this?

```
export default function MyFamily({ navigation, props, person, inheritors }) {
  console.log(getFamily());

  let [family, setFamily] = useState(getFamily());

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(getFamily());
    setFamily(getFamily());
  }, [getFamily]);
```

In the screen where I set the Family again I do this:
And I know that's correct because the Json that is shown shows the updated value.

```
import { setFamily } from '../../utilities/family';
setFamily(responseJson.family);
```

This is the way family is formulated:

```
let family = '';
export default family;
export function getFamily() {
  return family;
}
export function setFamily(f) {
  family = f;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

React doesn't actually know that the value returned from the `getFamily` function changes each render. In the `useState` function, it's only used in the initial state, and the `useEffect` function never gets re-run because the `getFamily` function itself doesn't ever change and re-trigger the `useEffect`. You have to change the `getFamily()` function to use a state that's stored in a parent component and pass it into the MyFamily component as a prop.

e.g.

```
// the parent component that renders the MyFamily screen
function Router() {
  const [family, setFamily] = useState('')

  return (
    <Navigator>
    <Screen component={<MyFamily family={family} setFamily={setFamily} />
    <Screen component={<OtherComponent family={family} setFamily={setFamily} />
    </Navigator>
  }
  )
}
```

And then from `MyFamily`:

```
function MyFamily({ family }) {
  console.log(family); // this should be updated
}
```

and from `OtherComponent`:

```
function OtherComponent({ setFamily }) {
  return (<Button onClick={() => setFamily('newFamily')>Change family</Button>)
}
```

Comment: Mmm okey, but how could I do that?

Comment: Okey thank you. But now in the `MyFamily` I get the error because it says 'identifier family has already been declared' wich is correct cause that is done like this: `  const family = getFamily();
`

Comment: You don't need that line anymore since you usually don't want to call a getter function in the top-level of a react component; you can just use the `family` prop instead of the `getFamily` getter (in fact, you can remove `getFamily` entirely)